# How to find the jasper report compiler version of a jasper server whose version is 7.2.0

Tags: jasperserver

I am trying to find the version of the jasper compiler used in our jasper server (v7.2.0), and I am absolutely stumped, as I cannot find it anywhere. What server file should I look at, or is there a default version of the jasper compiler for server v7.2.0?
Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

Find in you server:

Path: <path_install>/webapps/jasperserver-pro/WEB-INF/lib

The lib: jasperreports-x.x.x.jar

Example, my version compiler is jasperreports-6.11.0

[image: library version jasperreports]

Regards.